# Old show set in China: a girl that could turn into a snake and a Liu Kang looking guy

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a show as a child but I can't remember the storyline or name.

All I remember is the intro included a girl who could turn into a snake and a guy who kind of looked like Liu Kang from *Mortal Kombat*; he could also manipulate fire I believe.

Also I'm pretty sure it was set in China.

Possibly a CITV or Cartoon Network show.

Comment: You could help with some details Josh. Can you guess a year when you saw it? How old are you now? How old were you then? Did you see it on UK TV? Was it English Language? Was it subtitled? Do you mean CITV or CCTV? What were the FX like? Good or bad? DId ya mean Liu Kang or Raiden? Have you Googled "China snake woman" have you seen this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXft6Qd5nWE

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)